# Auto-number table rows?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following HTML table:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like each row in this table have a number automatically assigned to each item.

How could he do?

Comment: Why? that's a static table of three row, just type 1, 2 ,3

Comment: You can't unless you use some scripting.

Comment: Can you specify what do you want exactly, and for wich reason you want to achieve this. That will help us to help you more effciency.

Comment: Ok, but what I wanted was a number, 1,2,3,4 ... automatically each row. :(

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The following CSS enumerates table rows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RyGX/)):

```css
table {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr::before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
  content: counter(rowNumber) ".";
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td>blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td>red</td></tr>
  <tr><td>yellow</td></tr>
  <tr><td>green</td></tr>
  <tr><td>purple</td></tr>
  <tr><td>orange</td></tr>
  <tr><td>maroon</td></tr>
  <tr><td>mauve</td></tr>
  <tr><td>lavender</td></tr>
  <tr><td>pink</td></tr>
  <tr><td>brown</td></tr>
</table>
```

If the CSS cannot be used, try the following JavaScript code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RyGX/1/)):

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  rows[i].children[0][text] = i + ': ' + rows[i].children[0][text];
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 I deleted my answer since I didn't bother to provide a fix for `.textContent`, but I'd really suggest using the `.rows` and `.cells`  collections that are automatically provided instead of `getElementsByTagName()` and `.children`.

Comment: The css code works for me but the first td starts from 2. instead from 1. Maybe it counts the th as a td and thus starts from 2... In any case, You can view it here: http://benia.biz/pricing ... Would appreciate a solution for this and gladly give the bounty for it.

Comment: @Benia: just use `table.rows` instead of `table.getElementsByTagName('tr')` as already mentioned in first comment?

Comment: Mind blown, I never knew about counter for css.

Comment: @Craig: I'm glad to have introduced you to something fun!

Comment: The CSS solution works great indeed. You could change `table tr` to `table tbody tr`  to make sure it starts counting at 1 instead of 2.

Comment: I recommend `tr::before {
  display: table-cell;
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}`

Answer (score 30):

And if you would use headers as well the following is the thing you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RyGX/

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr:not(:first-child) {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

note the: ":not(:first-child)" in there.

Comment: You've linked to a JS Fiddle demo that doesn't include the jQuery in your question. If you add the jQuery and (presumably) remove the CSS in that JS Fiddle that already makes it work, and then hit the 'update' button towards the top of the screen, you'll have a demo that demonstrates *your* code rather than mine. Which should be more useful to you, I'd think. Otherwise, you can use 'Stack Snippets' to embed front-end (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) based code into your answer (click [edit], and then the `</>` button above the textarea).

Comment: Thank you! The accepted answer causes issues with the header, this one has none! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Here is a modification of David Thomas' CSS solution that works with or without a header row in the table. It increments the counter on the first `td` cell of each row (thereby skipping the row with only `th` cells):

```
table
{
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr > td:first-child
{
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before
{
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

You can see the behavior in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/p7q3yr5f/).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a javascript solution that will add a cell at the beginning of each row , this cell will be used for numbering, if there is a `th` cell this gets a `colspan=2` attribute.

```js
var addNumeration = function(cl){
  var table = document.querySelector('table.' + cl)
  var trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr')
  var counter = 1
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(trs, function(x,i){
    var firstChild = x.children[0]
    if (firstChild.tagName === 'TD') {
      var cell = document.createElement('td')
      cell.textContent = counter ++
      x.insertBefore(cell,firstChild)
    } else {
      firstChild.setAttribute('colspan',2)
    }
  })
}

addNumeration("test")
```

```html
<table class="test" border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>hi!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This it the best solution for me. How can we add another row on top with letters a-z?