# automatically change numbering on deleting a row

Tags: jquery

I want a table row having a checked checkbox to be deleted after clicking a button. I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function(i){
        $(this).children('td:eq(0)').append(i+1);

        //button click
        $('.deletebtn').click(function(){     
            $('table input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')==true?$('table input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked").parent('td').parent('tr').remove():$('table input[type="checkbox"]').parent('tr').show()
        });
    });  
});
```

This is not working only because of `.is(":checked")` in the `if statement` if i remove it, the code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function(i){
        $(this).children('td:eq(0)').append(i+1);

        //button click
        $('.deletebtn').click(function(){     
            $('table input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')==true?$('table input[type="checkbox"]').parent('td').parent('tr').remove():$('table input[type="checkbox"]').parent('tr').show()
        });
    }); 
});
```

This code deletes all the rows, obviously because i did not indicate the checked checkbox. So it takes `$('table input[type="checkbox"]').parent('td').parent('tr')` as all the rows.

NOTE: Besides this, I also want the numbering alongside each checkbox to be auto-updated on deleting a row.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RZWt/1/

Comment: you added 2 dots in front op the `prop()` method in your jsfiddle

Comment: `.is(":checked")` returns a boolean, you cannot chain it with jQuery methods. Use `filter()` instead. For updating rows number, you should use CSS instead, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012547/1414562  BTW, your posted jsFiddle doesn't match your posted code...

Comment: Do you want [__this__](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7pAQb/)

Comment: You want this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/3RZWt/4/ ?

Answer (score 3):

*I want a table row having a checked checkbox to be deleted after clicking a button. Besides this, I also want the numbering alongside each checkbox to be auto-updated on deleting a row.*

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Set Numbers to span
    function AutoNumber() {
        $('table tr').each(function (i) {
            $(this).find('span').text(i);
        });
    }
    //button slick
    $('.deletebtn').click(function () {
        $('table tr').each(function (i) {
            if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
        //After deletion
        AutoNumber();
    });
    //Call to set initially
    AutoNumber();
});
```

*HTML*, Added span to first cell

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" /><span></span>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7pAQb/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS for the row counter and fixed a little your code:

### --DEMO--

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deletebtn').click(function () {
        $('table input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```