# automatically add serial numbers to table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i have a dynamic table, that displays a list of footbal clubs from numbers 1 - 20, i am trying to automatically assign psoition numbers to the the position row, either by javascript or css, i have done some searching but havent seen anything usefull, so i am asking how to go about this. here is my table

```
<table width="100%">
        <tr style="color:#fff" bgcolor="#FF0099">
          <td>Pos</td>
          <td>Club</td>
          <td>Pts</td>
          <td>P</td>
          <td>W</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>L</td>
          <td>GD</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php do { ?>
        <tr style="color:#FFf" bgcolor="#00a99d">
          <td bgcolor="#00a99d"></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['Club']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['Pts']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['Pld']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['W']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['d']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['L']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_tab['Gd']; ?></td>
          <td><a href="table_update.php?id=<?php echo $row_tab['id']; ?>">Administer</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_tab = mysql_fetch_assoc($tab)); ?>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why? `tr`s have [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex) property already.

Comment: Hey do you want `Jquery` code

Comment: maybe i meant the td, anyways what am trying to achieve is, if u look at my table, you will notice column pos has no values, i want to populate it automatically

Comment: ok neeraj lets see that, thanks

Comment: why don't you just print out your rownumbers via a php variable?

Comment: Please write what you mean ; ). Anyway, `td`s have [`cellIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) as well.

Comment: You should edit your question again if you want to do it for columns

Comment: Kindly have a look at this following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012421/auto-number-table-rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this css style (no javascript is required):

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UMjaE/)

#### Update

To specify the table first add an id or class to your table:

```
<table width="100%" id="team-list">
```

Modify the styles:

```
table#team-list {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table#team-list tr:nth-child(n+1) {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table#team-list tr:nth-child(n+1) td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Where n+**1** is the number from where it should start indexing. 
Ex: n+10 starts counting from 10th row.

Comment: cool, but can i specify a particular table, as i have diff tables, and also specify the row it starts from, thanks

Comment: you, sir, just completely blew my mind. I have never ever thought of doing that!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table width="100%">
            <tr style="color:#fff" bgcolor="#FF0099">
              <td>Pos</td>
              <td>Club</td>
              <td>Pts</td>
              <td>P</td>
              <td>W</td>
              <td>D</td>
              <td>L</td>
              <td>GD</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
//declare your counter here
 do {
//increase your counter by 1 here
 ?>
            <tr style="color:#FFf" bgcolor="#00a99d">
              <td bgcolor="#00a99d"><<Use your counter here>></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['Club']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['Pts']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['Pld']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['W']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['d']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['L']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_tab['Gd']; ?></td>
              <td><a href="table_update.php?id=<?php echo $row_tab['id']; ?>">Administer</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } while ($row_tab = mysql_fetch_assoc($tab)); ?>
          </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for serial no.

```
function recalcId() {           
        $.each($("#tblEmpData tr:not(:first)"), function (i, el) {
            $(this).find("td:first").text(i + 1); // Simply couse the first "prototype" is not counted in the list                
        })

    }
```

Hope it likes you

Comment: thanks but i have seen something like this, it dosent feel my requirement, in the sense that it dosent start from the particular row i want it to start from, with this code, the title pos is also counted

Answer (score 0):

This Is Another Way To Do It Pure CSS No Javascript

```css
 body {
            counter-reset: Serial;   /* Set the Serial counter to 0 */
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
        }
        tr td:first-child:before {
            counter-increment: Serial;      /* Increment the Serial counter */
            content:counter(Serial); /* Display the counter */
        }
```