# CSS auto numbers for table rows - not first?

Tags: css

I have the following code which is used to apply a row count to a dynamic table -

```
.ftable table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

.ftable tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.ftable tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Which came from ([Auto-number table rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012421/auto-number-table-rows))

Is it possible to ignore the first row (first row is my header row - which has a class of fble_htr if thats any help)

Comment: You could put your first row in a `thead` element and other rows in `tbody`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes:

```
.ftable tr:not(.fble_htr) {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.ftable tr:not(.fble_htr) td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Instead of `tr:not(.fble_htr)`, you could also use `tr:not(:first-child)` or `tr + tr`.

As mentioned in the comments, if you can modify your HTML, another option is to move your header row into a `thead` element, and the rest of the rows into a `tbody` element, then select `.ftable tbody tr` instead of `.ftable tr:not(.fble_htr)`.

Comment: `tr:not(:first-child)` working perfectly. and is more readable

Answer (score 8):

if you marked the table right the first row should be thead and so you can use:

```
.rlstable {
 counter-reset: row-num;
}
.rlstable tbody tr  {
counter-increment: row-num;
}

.rlstable tr td:first-child::before {
content: counter(row-num) ". ";
}
.rlstable tr td:first-child {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: but the first answer is more complete.