# Retain zebra striping of table after rows are filtered with Alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js

I have a table that has zebra striping.

I'm using Alpine.js to filter rows based on buttons you click.

When the table is filtered, the row striping is from the original, unfiltered state.

I'd like the striping to be recalculated when the filter is updated.

Code is below and I've created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tyssen/pen/mdpaYjR).

```
<div x-data="{ filterID: 'all', filter: (id, allowed) => allowed.includes(id) }">
  <nav class="mb-4">
    <a
      class="bg-purple-200 hover:bg-purple-400"
      @click.prevent="filterID = 'all', striping"
      :class="{ 'bg-purple-400' : filterID === 'all' }"
      href="#"
    >All</a>
    <a
      class="bg-purple-200 hover:bg-purple-400"
      @click.prevent="filterID = 'A'"
      :class="{ 'bg-purple-400' : filterID === 'A' }"
      href="#"
    >A</a>
    <a
      class="bg-purple-200 hover:bg-purple-400"
      @click.prevent="filterID = 'B'"
      :class="{ 'bg-purple-400' : filterID === 'B' }"
      href="#"
    >B</a>
  </nav>
  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        x-show.transition="filter(filterID, [ 'A' ]) || filterID === 'all'"
        :class="{ 'active': filter(filterID, [ 'A' ]) }"
        class=""
      >
        <td>Data 1A</td>
        <td>Data 1B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr
        x-show.transition="filter(filterID, [ 'B' ]) || filterID === 'all'"
        :class="{ 'active': filter(filterID, [ 'B' ]) }"
        class="bg-purple-200"
      >
        <td>Data 2A</td>
        <td>Data 2B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr
        x-show.transition="filter(filterID, [ 'A' ]) || filterID === 'all'"
        :class="{ 'active': filter(filterID, [ 'A' ]) }"
        class=""
      >
        <td>Data 3A</td>
        <td>Data 3B</td>
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should make the CSS dependent on the [rownumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248005/css-auto-numbers-for-table-rows-not-first) ?

Comment: @Luuk That's an interesting idea but I can't figure out how to use that to apply styles to the whole row.

Comment: It seems rownumbers are applied before filtering, see: https://codepen.io/Luuk34/pen/QWaYWKz, which uses [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with even/odd.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. With your example (mine too), if I select A, it goes blue, blue, red, rather than blue, red, blue (or red, blue, red) which is what I want.

Comment: I was (trying) to say that using rownumbers does not seem to work, because the CSS is also applied to filtered rownumber, which make you see: blue,blue,red   (and not blue,red,blue) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:key="row.id"` in order to give those items specific ids. This way, alpine.js will remove the inactive rows from the DOM so the odd/even count will not be messed up with the rows being hidden.

Comment: Thanks. I'd actually already got this working on my dev site but hadn't gotten around to updating the CodePen. The code in the CodePen had also changed substantially from what I posted above in the original question too.