# PHP MySQL auto-numbering rows with a dependency and add as column

Tags: php, mysql

A question for my discgolf scoresystem.

I have a HTML table filled with data from a MySQL query.
Like this:

```
$uke_resultat_query = "SELECT * FROM Sammenlagt WHERE Dato='$select_box_value'";
$uke_resultat = mysql_query($uke_resultat_query);
```

`$select_box_value` is the value from a select box with certain values.

The table goes

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($uke_resultat)){   
echo    "<tr><td>" . $row['Dato'] . "</td>

// Somwhere here i want to add a column that counts player's position...
// 1st place as the number 1 and so forth..
// The column called 'Poeng' will determine the order
// Players with even score will get the same position

            <td>
    <a href=\"/wordpress/teststats?id=". $row["spillerid"]."\">" . $row['Navn'] . "</a>
            </td>
            <td>" . $row['hull1'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull2'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull3'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull4'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull5'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull6'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull7'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull8'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull9'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull10'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull11'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull12'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull13'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull14'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull15'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull16'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull17'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['hull18'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Sammenlagt'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Par'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['Poeng'] . "</td></tr>";  
}
?>
```

I've tried to explain in comments inside the code above, but to be clear on my question:
**How can I add a column with position that checks the score from column "Poeng" and adds the correct position to the scoreboard?**
 *Only rule to add is that if two players have the same score, they will be given the same position like:*

```
1 Johnny Ace  65 (points)
2 Billy Bogey 63
2 Perry Par   63
4 Bob Birdie  60
etc..
```

Can it be done with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

Yes, it can be done with PHP. **added this to the beginning of the while loop**:

```
$plassering = 0;
$forrige_sum = 0;
$hoppet_over= 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($uke_resultat)){   //Creates a loop

    if($forrige_sum != $row['Poeng']){
            $plassering += (1 + $hoppet_over);
            $hoppet_over = 0;
    } else {
        $hoppet_over += 1;
    }
        $forrige_sum = $row['Poeng'];

echo    "<tr>
<td>" . $plassering . "</td>
<td>
<a href=\"/wordpress/teststats?id=". $row["spillerid"]."\">"
. $row['Navn'] . "</a>
</td>
<td>" . $row['hull1'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['hull2'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['hull3'] . "</td>

........
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL Statement.

```
$uke_resultat_query = "SELECT * FROM Sammenlagt WHERE Dato='$select_box_value' ORDER BY Poeng";
```

With ORDER BY you get from the database an ordered result.

Comment: Thank you but ordering is not the issue. I need to build an additional column as described.

Comment: Why can't you bring the data ordered? What you describe you want is easily achieved by order by. If we assume that order by can't be used, your question become "simulating order by from within php"

Comment: Well, ORDER will get the list in the correct order, but in addition to that i want to build a column that shows the positions, as described in the question. By the little I know of this, it appears to be easier to fix this with php rather than some rule setting in the db. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use CSS to "number" the list. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012421/auto-number-table-rows

Comment: OK, so CSS can add a number inside the table cell where I want. What i need, is a column to the left of my MySQL-generated table. This column will mark the score positions from 1st place (winner) to the very last player on the scoreboard. As described in my question, there is a rule to this numbering which is depending on the players score. I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: @iontomet so you're saying you want to `UPDATE` the record inside the database containing the position of that person? Do you want to see the table or you're just making this so you can classify who won inside the database?

Comment: No, I don't want to `UPDATE` or change the database. I want to add a column to the presentation of the scoreboard as it is displayed on the website. Data in the database remains as is. As the code is now, I only get the sorted list of players, the date and their score. Already sorted via a view. So after this information is fetched from the database, it is looped and spread out in a HTML table. Lastly i would like to have a column added that provides the position of each player.  Should this discussion be moved to a chat or something?