# Counting added fields in nested form (cocoon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I got a nested form using the cocoon gem:

_form.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for @day do |f|
  #task
    = f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task|
      = render 'task_fields', f: task
    .links
      = link_to_add_association '+ Aufgabe', f, :tasks
  = f.submit
```

_task_fields.html.haml:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :description, label: 'Name/Beschreibung: '
  = f.input :ur, as: :range, input_html: { min: '1', max: '4', id: "rangeInput#{@x}", oninput: "rangeOutput#{@x}.value = rangeInput#{@x}.value"}
  %output#rangeOutput{:for => "rangeInput#{@x}", :name => "rangeOutput#{@x}"} 3

  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

days_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @day = current_user.days.build(day_params)
  @day.save
  respond_to do |format|
    if @day.save
      format.html { redirect_to @day, notice: 'Day was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @day }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @day.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I need to increment a viariable evertime  the `_task_fields-partial` is rendered or the `link_to_add_association` is pressed.

Comment: Could you share your relevant controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration and add the column `:view_count` to your nested attribute.

In your controller for the `nested attribute`, in the `create` method add this line:

```
@day.increment!(:view_count)
```

This would increment 1 every time the `create` method is called. Im not sure how you want to display the number but in the view you can do this:

```
<%= @day.view_count %>
```

Or you could use `@day.tasks.count` which would give you the count.

Comment: I thought the create method is only called once when the submitbutton is clicked, but I need to increase a variable everytime the `link_to_add_association` is pressed

Comment: After you click the link_to_add_association button, the next thing to do would be to create the nested value, so the create method will be called, which would give you the number of nested values

Comment: I think, you get me wrong, I need this variable before the submitbutton is pressed and before this has happened the createmethod would not be called

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you could just solve this in css. So if you want to display a row/item-number, but actually the number is not relevant to you, you could do something like: [Auto-number table rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012421/auto-number-table-rows)

Otherwise you will need to use the js callbacks, where upon insertion or removal you can calculate and display the number. As an example, you could use this to limit the maximum number of allowed nested items: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/How-to-limit-the-number-of-nested-fields