# ngFor and enumerate rows

Tags: angular

I'm creating a table using `ngFor` using an `Observable` as source:

```
<tr *ngFor="let payment of sources$ | async">
```

I'd like to add an enumerable on the first column of this table:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Of course, each `1,2` or `3` is the position of the current `payment` inside the table.
Is there any elegant way to get it?

Comment: You can even do it using CSS counters as it's described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012547/731178

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's extremely easy. Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let payment of sources$; let i = index;">
  <td>{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

*Index* is a simple Angular2 functionality, like *odd*, *even* or *last*. You can read more about it [in official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html).

If you using pipe, you code should look like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let payment of sources$ | async; let i = index;">
    <td>{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where does `index` come from?