# PHP Table row numbering

Tags: php, html-table, row

The code below produces a table as shown in the attached picture. I need to edit the code so that instead of 'Yay!', the '#' column displays the row number (starting with row 1)

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">Yup'ik</th>
  <th scope="col">English</th>
  <th scope="col">Audio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
  #cycle through rows
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    print("<tr>");
    print("<th scope='row'>Yay!</th>”);

    #cycle through columns
     print("<td>$file[0]</td>");
     print("<td>$file[1]</td>");
     print("<td><a href='audio/$file[2]'>$file[2]</a></td>");
     print("</tr>");
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Table]

Comment: you also have a parse error here, `</th>”`< right there, being a curly quote.

Comment: Did you know you can do row numbers with CSS? I just learned it myself, although it doesn't really surprise me that it's possible. Pretty neat though, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012421/auto-number-table-rows (I'm not saying you should use that here necessarily. I just thought it was interesting and related.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Come to think of it, I remember I was working on something many moons ago which resembled that a lot. I call that part of "my good 'ol days".

Comment: i would just use  the `$files` array key (+1)

Comment: @IdontDownVote I agree, makes sense, assuming the index is numeric/sequential.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a counter staring from 1 a.g. $counter=1;
Print the counter instead of 'Yay' and increment it inside the foreach loop:  $counter++;