# Ordered list spanning table rows

Tags: html, markdown

I want to create a question form in a Markdown/HTML page, with each question having a number.

```
 QUESTIONS         |  ANSWERS          |
-------------------|-------------------|
1. First Question  |                   |
-------------------|-------------------|
2. Second Question |                   | 
-------------------|-------------------|
3. Third Question  |                   |
-------------------|-------------------|
```

It seems the best way to do this is as a table. But code like this:

```
        <td>
            <ol>
                <li>First Question</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <ol>
                <li>Second Question</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <ol>
                <li>Third Question</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Gives me a table like this:

```
 QUESTIONS         |  ANSWERS          |
-------------------|-------------------|
1. First Question  |                   |
-------------------|-------------------|
1. Second Question |                   | 
-------------------|-------------------|
1. Third Question  |                   |
-------------------|-------------------|
```

When I try googling this, I see instructions on how to have an ordered list **within** a table cell.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the "ol" element outside your table definition, and then just the "li" elements within the table cells.

```
<ol>
<table>
<tr><td>QUESTIONS</td><td>ANSWERS</td></tr>
<tr><td><li>First Question</li></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><li>Second Question</li></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><li>Third Question</li></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</ol>
```

Comment: I was sure this would work, but `<li>` lines are automatically surrounded by `<ul>` and `</ul>` and appear as bullets!

Comment: Hi.  "Automatically surrounded" by what?  I made a simple HTML file (like the example in my answer) and tested it myself with current Firefox, Chrome and Edge (on Windows) and it renders the table with numbered items.  Is it whatever tool you are using to create your HTML that is adding the "ul" tags?  There are also CSS options, if you're not able to get the solution in my answer to work - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012421/auto-number-table-rows

Comment: My HTML that I tested   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ol>
<table>
<tr><td>QUESTIONS</td><td>ANSWERS</td></tr>
<tr><td><li>First Question</li></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><li>Second Question</li></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><li>Third Question</li></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</ol>

</body>
</html>

Comment: I'm using a knowledgebase tool called Document360, whose pages can be edited in WYSIWYG or markdown. I pasted your code into the markdown editor, switched to the WYSIWYG, and saw the behavior I mentioned. I switched back to markdown, and saw the code as I described it. I'm guessing that its my editor that does this. (I'm giving you the checkmark because I'm sure  your answer works anywhere else!)

Comment: Yeah, it can be a tricky one sometimes.  Your editor is changing it because why?  (well, ultimately, it's changing it because someone has coded rules within it about how tags should appear in different circumstances).  I'm certainly not HTML expert - others may have comments on this.  I would kind of figure that if it was strictly invalid HTML that all of the browsers I tested would not render as expected.  Maybe Document360 is just expecting that "li" tags within a table cell should have an opening "ol" or "ul" tag also within the cell .....